# How to handle each response in successCallBack of promises in case of dynamic passage of promises to .when()

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise

Here are the cloud functions namely 'batchReq1' and batchPromises.

In any case, if I know the exact number of promises pushed (Consider the size of results to be '2' in function batchPromises(results)) and executed through when(), I can handle the success response by passing that number of result parameters (In the below example request1, request2) in successCallBack of .then().

If I have to process the number of promises pushed to .when() dynamically, then, how can we handle this in SuccessCallBack? Unlike earlier scenario, we can't expect fixed number of results in the then method (batchPromises(results).then(function (result1, result2) {....)

**batchReq1**

```
Parse.Cloud.define("batchReq1", function (request, response) {

    var results = request.params.imageArray;


    batchPromises(results).then(function (result1, result2) {

            console.log("Final Result:: Inside Success");

            console.log("Final Result:: Inside Success result 1::::"+result1);
            console.log("Final Result:: Inside Success result 2::::"+result2);

            response.success();

        }



//    batchPromises(results).then(function (arraySuccess) {
//
//        console.log("Final Result:: Inside Success");
//        console.log("Final Result:: Inside Success:: Length:: "+arraySuccess.length);
//        //Fetch all responses from promises and display
//        var _ = require('underscore.js');
//        _.each(arraySuccess, function (result) {
//
//            console.log("Final Result:: " + result)
//
//        });
//
//
//        response.success();
//
//    }



        , function (error) {
        console.log("Final Result:: Inside Error");
        response.error(error);

    });

});
```

**batchPromises**

```
function batchPromises(results) {

    var promise = Parse.Promise.as();
    var promises = [];


    var increment = 0;
    var isFromParallelExecution = false;


    var _ = require('underscore.js');
    _.each(results, function (result) {




        var tempPromise = Parse.Promise.as("Promise Resolved ");
        promises.push(tempPromise);
        }


            promise = promise.then(function () {

               return Parse.Promise.when(promises);

            });

        }
        increment++;
    });

    return promise;
}
```

Comment: can you refactor this so people can read it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how i handle this...

```
Parse.Cloud.define("xxx", function(request, response) 
{   
    var channels = ["channel1", "channel2", "channel3", "channel4", "channel5"];
    var queries = new Array();

    for (var i = 0; i < channels.length; i++)
    {
        var query = new Parse.Query(channels[i]);
        queries.push(query.find());
    }   

    Parse.Promise.when(queries).then(function()
    {
        var msg = "";
        for (var j = 0; j < arguments.length; j++)
        {       
            for (var k = 0; k < arguments[j].length; k++) 
            { 
                var object = arguments[j][k];
                msg = msg + "  " + object.get('somefield');
            }
        }
        response.success(msg);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. For time being, I had taken different approach.

Comment: Don't evaluate `length` in the 2nd argument of `for` on each loop, use `for(var j=0, l=arguments.length; j<l; ...` instead, or even better - `_.each` from underscore.

Answer (score 0):

Either you just use the [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) to loop over the results, or you build your `arraySuccess` without `when` - it doesn't make much sense here anyway as you batch the requests (executing them sequentially), instead of executing them in parallel:

```
function batchPromises(tasks) {
    var _ = require('underscore.js');
    _.reduce(tasks, function (promise, task) {
        return promise.then(function(resultArr) {
            var tempPromise = Parse.Promise.as("Promise Resolved for "+taks);

            return tempPromise.then(function(taskResult) {
                resultArr.push(taskResult);
                return resultArr;
            });
        });
    }, Parse.Promise.as([]));
}
```

If you actually wanted to execute them in parallel, use a simple

```
function batchPromises(tasks) {
    var _ = require('underscore.js');
    return Parse.Promise.when(_.map(tasks, function (task) {
        return Parse.Promise.as("Promise Resolved for "+taks);
    }).then(function() {
        return [].slice.call(arguments);
    });
}
```